# How can I find a set of random numbers that sum to a specific number?

Tags: php

This is my code below. The code itself echoes if the sum of three of random numbers equals 100. For now to get a result of 100 as `$valuestotal` I have to reload the page a lot. But I want to get the result of 100 as `$valuestotal` every time I reload the page. How can I do this?

I thought it would be possible with a loop in loop. But it gives the same result x times. I want PHP to keep trying different random values, and when it reaches to the value of 100 as `$valuestotal`, it should echo the `$valuestotal`...

What I really want is, for example, I want three random numbers to get total of 100, example is 35 and 25 and 50. Or 25 and 15 and 60... the list goes on...

How is this possible?

```
$values = rand(1, 100);
$values2 = rand(1, 100);
$values3 = rand(1, 100);

$valuestotal = $values + $values2 + $values3;

        //

while ($valuestotal === 100)
{
    echo $values;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $values2;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $values3;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $valuestotal;

}
```

Comment: what is there to loop .? try an if($valuestotal === 100) {} else  {} see what happens.

Comment: I choosed the title as loop because i am trying to get my result via loop. But i am done lol. I want to loop my condition and when it reaches to the 100 of total, it should echo it, but if it did not reach, it should try to reach over and over again, i am so confused while doing this. // Edit : I tried if else and i did not get what i want.

Comment: you just want one probability or do you want to print more than one probabilities or all the probabilities?

Comment: I want to loop multiple times until it finds the result of 100 (as total of 3 variables)... Will look to the answers, thank you for all!

Comment: @OzanŞiarPalik : please think of [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 4):

One more possible approach. The code is slightly more complex than some of the other answers, but I wanted to add one way that would only need to loop once.

```
$target = 100;
$n = 3;

while ($n) {
    if (1 < $n--) {
        $addend = rand(0, $target - ($n - 1));
        $target -= $addend;
        $addends[] = $addend;
    } else {
        $addends[] = $target;
    }
}

var_dump($addends);
```

Basically you subtract a random number between 0 and the remainder of the previous subtraction *n* times until there's only one repetition left, and the remainder is the last piece. `$n - 1` is there so that it doesn't randomly subtract too much for there to be enough left for the rest of the repetitions.

Answer (score 3):

In a `while` loop, the block will be execute as long as the condition is
true. So you can think, what do  you have to execute multiple times, and
when should it stop?

What  you need  to execute  multiple times  is the  gathering of  random
numbers:

```
while ( ... ) {
    # roll dice, save numbers
}
```

Now this should stop  when sum is 100. The condition  stated in the loop
must be true for  it to run multiple times, so in this  sense, it has to
run  while the  sum is  *not* 100.  Here  is a  key point  that you  got
reversed. If your condition is false  (by chance it will likely be after
first run) then the loop already stopped.  You have to run while the sum
is not 100 so  that when it is, it won't  gather random numbers anymore.
Then you proceed with echoing them.

```
$valuestotal = 0;

while ($valuestotal != 100) {

    $value1 = rand(1, 100);
    $value2 = rand(1, 100);
    $value3 = rand(1, 100);

    $valuestotal = $value1 + $value2 + $value3;
}

echo "$value1<br>$value2<br>$value3<br>$valuestotal";
```

---

As an alternative syntax, you could store the values in an array and use
the [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) function:

```
$numbers = [];

while (array_sum($numbers) != 100)
    $numbers = [
        rand(1, 100),
        rand(1, 100),
        rand(1, 100),
    ];

echo join(' + ', $numbers), ' = ', array_sum($numbers);
```

Comment: just saw this be4 I post an answer (not needed anymore now, and avoided DV too compared to this ^^), and it's clean and efficient +1 (although @Twisty's answer is cool too).

Comment: @OzanŞiarPalik glad to help :) thank you for the good question. There are many approaches to solving this, as you can see by the great diversity of answers you received!

Answer (score 2):

You will not need to loop inside of a loop. For example, you could do this:

```
<?php
$keepChecking = true;
$values = 0;
$values2 = 0;
$values3 = 0;
$valuestotal = 0;
while($keepChecking){
    $values = rand(1, 100);
    $values2 = rand(1, 100);
    $values3 = rand(1, 100);
    $valuestotal = $values + $values2 + $values3;
    if ($valuestotal === 100){
        $keepChecking = false;
    } 
}
echo $values;
echo '<br>';
echo $values2;
echo '<br>';
echo $values3;
echo "<br>";
echo $valuestotal;
?>
```

Results may be:

```
2
37
61
100
```

Can test here: http://phpfiddle.org/lite

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $valuesTotal = 0;
        while ($valuesTotal != 100){
            $value1 = rand(1, 100);
            $value2 = rand(1, 100);
            $value3 = rand(1, 100);
            $valuesTotal = $value1+$value2+$value3;
            echo "\$value1 = $value1 :: \$value2 = $value2 :: \$value3 = $value3 :: \$valuesTotal = $valuesTotal";

        }
?>
```

Another way :

```
<?php

        while (true){
            $value1 = rand(1, 100);
            $value2 = rand(1, 100);
            $value3 = rand(1, 100);
            $valuesTotal = $value1+$value2+$value3;
            echo "\$value1 = $value1 :: \$value2 = $value2 :: \$value3 = $value3 :: \$valuesTotal = $valuesTotal";
            if($valuesTotal == 100){
                break;
            }
        }
?>
```

This should give you an Idea, it may take a fraction of second to complete the script, or it could take forever, depending on your luck!

You need to write the code to be repeatedly executed between the brackets of your loop, not on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get only 2 random numbers which sum up to less than 100, than subtract that sum from 100 to get the 3rd random random. This function does just that in a simplistic manner:

```
function get_three_rand_numbs_sum_hundred(){

  $num1 = rand(1, 99);  // Get first random number.
  $num2 = rand(1, 99);  // Get second random number.
  $num3 = 0; // Declare variable which will evnetually hold 3rd random number.

  /* While the sum of the first 2 random numbers above is more than a 100,
  get another random number for Number 2.*/
  while(($num1 + $num2) >= 100){
    $num2 = rand(1, 99);
  }

  // Get the 3rd random number by subtracting the sum of the first two from 100.
  $num3 = 100 - ($num1 + $num2); 

  echo "Number 1 : ".$num1."\n";
  echo "Number 2 : ".$num2."\n";
  echo "Number 3 : ".$num3."\n";
  echo "Sum : ".($num3+$num2+$num1)."\n";
}
```

**NOTE:** The rand() function treats the max parameter provided to it as an exclusive value, so you should use 99 instead of a 100 since you are certain you do not want 100 from only 1 variable.

Answer (score 0):

Randomise the values inside a loop and each time set  a new value to  `$valuestotal` the loop will only stop if `$valuestotal = 100`.

```
$valuestotal = 0;

//

while ($valuestotal !== 100) {
    echo $values;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $values2;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $values3;
    echo "<br>";
    $values = rand(1, 100);
    $values2 = rand(1, 100);
    $values3 = rand(1, 100);
    echo $valuestotal . '<br>';
    $valuestotal = $values + $values2 + $values3;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
$count = 53;    
$total = 500;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $arr[] = 0;
}

for ($j = 0; $j < $total; $j++)
{
    $arr[rand() % $count]++;
}

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Hey, it will generate 53 number randomly that the sum of all 53 number is 500 :)

Comment: It's unique but not a good solution.  It will distribute almost evenly. Plus, what if $total = 1e20?

Comment: @ITgoldman now there is a question! dose php can store 1e20 or not ?

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you need to get 3 different random values whose sum is 100

Try This

```
$total = 100;
$val1 = rand(1,$total);
$val2 = rand(1, ($total-$val1));
$val3 = $total - ($val1 + $val2);
print($val1."\n");
print($val2."\n");
print($val3."\n");
```