# How can i set input hidden's value as countup timer's value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php

Basicly i have a timer javascript code, but it is a countup one, so when it stops and clearInterval(timer) runs, i want to make my input hidden change dynamically by the value of timer.

Example is :

When countup reaches to the 5 and if it stops, i want to make my input hidden have value of 5. Is this possible?

Reason is : I want to make a basic scoreboard depending on the time. With this value, people's score recording as sec. That is what i'm thinking.

JS Code is :

```
var sec = 0;

function pad(val) {
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
    {if ($("#character").is(':hidden'))
{    clearInterval(timer);
}}
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
}, 60000);
```

HTML code is :

```
  <form action="kayit.php">
  Ismini gir : <input type="text">
  <input id="score" type="hidden" value="I want that value changed dynamically as second." >
  <input type="submit" value="Onayladim">
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the value of a hidden input by assigning to its value property.

```
document.getElementById('score').value = Number(document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML) + (Number(document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML) * 60);
```

Though you might be better off just updating the value as you tick up your timer.

Heads up, setInterval isn't precise and won't be guaranteed to be invoked exactly every 1000ms.

EDIT ---
here is a fiddle that might help you https://jsfiddle.net/ftp1Lsjt/

```js
var sec = 0;

function pad(val) {
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
    {if ($("#character").is(':hidden'))
{    
//clearInterval(timer);
document.getElementById('score').value = Number(document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML) + (Number(document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML) * 60);
}}
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
}, 60000);
```

```css
#character{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='seconds_wrap'>
<span id='seconds'></span> Seconds
</div>
<div id='minutes_wrap'>
<span id='minutes'></span> Minutes
</div>
<div id='character'>

</div>
<form action="kayit.php">
  Ismini gir : <input type="text">
  <input id="score" type="hidden" value="I want that value changed dynamically as second." >
  <input type="submit" value="Onayladim">
  </form>
```

Comment: It gives value of zero everytime i display, i linked that value to a php score page, but it gives 0 everytime. How can i update it automatically every seconds? Do i need php or js? I guees it works with Ajax? I'm new to Ajax by the way, but hopefully i will learn something. Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking to update the score on a single page you will do that in Javascript. If you need to reflect that state in the server side you will probably want to use ajax to post the updated value to the server. I'm afraid I can't offer more insight than that without knowing a lot more about the environment and goals of the code.

Comment: @OzanŞiarPalik consider accepting the answer by ticking the checkmark till it turns green. Do this for all answers in your other questions that may have solved them.

Comment: @OzanŞiarPalik You were also asked to do so [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686939/how-can-i-find-a-set-of-random-numbers-that-sum-to-a-specific-number#comment74420795_43686939) under another question of yours.